# Android Q External Storage Changes

Tags: java, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have gone through so many blogs and android official developers site to understand the recent changes by Android in their new release "Q". 
I have a Xamarin.Android application live and have READ AND WRITE EXTERNAL permission to download and read the PDF file tho the DOWNLOADS folder. Still, I'm not clear about the changes I need to make in my code to target Android Q. Till now I only understood that there will be a private sandbox for each application to store files which we can enable using ADB commands
adb shell sm set-isolated-storage on
But, if I want to store the files on external storage there will be some new permissions.
I'm still not understanding what changes do I need to make and what new permissions do I need to add.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Q, Google is breaking down these two permissions into more granular permissions, allowing the user to restrict an app so it can only read or write certain file types. Specifically, the new permissions in Android Q will let the user restrict an app so it can only:

- Read the locations from your media.
- Read or write music files.
- Read or write photos/image files.
- Read or write video files.

An app that has already been granted the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission prior to the user upgrading to Android Q will automatically be granted the “read” permissions listed above, but not the “write” permissions.

You can refer to this blog.

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-privacy-permission-controls/

Comment: More importantly, all read and write access seems to need to happen through the SAF, rather than via `File` paths.

Comment: Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.

Comment: Reply don't seems to be an answer. The question is still there. Can anyone share example of SAF for the above mentioned scenario.